# Extract text between quotes and insert after tag

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am a regex noobie and can't seem to wrap my head around it. Thing is, I don't have time as I am on the clock and need to do other things. I would love a straight answer with an explanation of how it works (if possible).

What I have:

```
<li id=\"B1031.001\"><a href=\"#\">Bolted shear tab gravity connections</a></li>
```

What I need:

```
<li id=\"B1031.001\"><a href=\"#\">B1031.001 - Bolted shear tab gravity connections</a></li>
```

Basically, I need to take the value of the 'id' attribute and prepend it do the a tag's text. I am hoping there is a way to do this in Notepad++ with regex to make the process faster.

Thank you for reading,
Patrick

Comment: Are the double quotes really escaped? Keep in mind that the good way to do that is to use an html parser with the language you want, instead of notepad++.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, although it wouldn't be too hard to find \" and replace with "

Comment: Yes, but i would be hard to search `\"` when it is only `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
search:  <li id=\\"([^"]+)\\"><a href=\\"#\\">\K
replace: $1 -      (<- there is a trailing space)
```

`\K` removes all that has been matched on the left from the match result. In other words, all that has been matched on the left is not replaced. The only thing that is replaced is the empty string after the `>` (from the `a` tag). *(The goal of the search pattern is only to capture the id value and to reach the insert position.)*

`([^"]+)` captures the content of the id attribute in group 1.  *(`[^"]` all that is not a double quote, `+` one or more times)*

`$1` refers to the content of this capture group.

Comment: When I search for the string, no error message appears but a label pops up below the line saying "^ zero length matched"

Comment: @PBarnum: Does it prevent the replacement?

Comment: Sorry about that, it worked beautifully! I wasn't clicking "replace all" but instead trying to find or replace one, which wasn't working. Accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ You can search :

```
 <li id=\\[\"](.*?)[\"]><a href=\\"#\\">
```

And replace it with:

```
<li id=\"$1\"><a href=\"#\">$1 -
```

Basically it will replace the whole String, but substituting $1 for the content matched by the regex inside the parenthesis.

Comment: "Find: Can't find the text <li id=[\"'](.*?)[\"']><a href=\"#\">"

Comment: Sorry. The code block ate some slashes, search for this instead: <li id=\\\[\"](.*?)[\"]><a href=\\"#\\">